# How JPA work with views?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Let's say if we create the following view

```
CREATE VIEW V_ABC AS 
SELECT TABLE_A.id as id, SUM(TABLE_A.a+TABLE_B.b-TABLE_C.c) as total, TABLE_A.a as a,TABLE_B.b as b,TABLE_C.c as c
FROM TABLE_A
join TABLE_B on TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.fid
join TABLE_C on TABLE_B.id = TABLE_C.fid
GROUP BY TABLE_A.a,TABLE_B.b,TABLE_C.c;
```

And map an entity to this view

```
public class VABC{
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private BigDecimal a;
    private BigDecimal b;
    private BigDecimal c;
```

}

my question is, within the J2EE application, each time when call any field from instance of `VABC`, like following:

```
VABC vabc = VABC.findById(id);
BigDecimal currentTotal = vabc.getTotal();
```

Does JPA has to execute the whole above query for the view then get current result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA does not know that it is a view, for it that is transparent, i.e it will try to select something like this:

```
SELECT f1,... FROM V_ABC where id=?
```

and the database will translate this to the corresponding `JOIN` & `SUM()` operations.

PS: In order to check that, you could enable logging of all SQL queries and see what is sent to the DB.

Comment: thank you. Also just to double confirm, is it actually the db query for the view `V_ABC` and is it only the JPQL to implement the `getter` method to retrieve the `SELECT total FROM V_ABC...` from the view query result?

Comment: Yes (you formulated it somehow vague). DB will actually do the view query/logic that you wrote when you defined the view. JPA will simply get some kind of Map fieldName=>fieldValue and will set the value to the corresponding Java property (e.g by calling the setter `setTotal()`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to easily map your view (a result set) into an entity class you can leverage so called *constructor expression*, one of JPQL or Criteria API features.

Assuming you have defined either JPQL or Criteria API query, for example:

JPQL

```
SELECT NEW com.dreamer.jpa.VABC(ta.id, SUM(ta.a + tb.b - tc.c), ta.a, tb.b, tc.c)
FROM TableA ta JOIN ta.b tb JOIN tb.c tc
WHERE ta.id = tb.fid AND tb.id = tc.fid
GROUP BY ta.a, tb.b, tc.c
```

Criteria API

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TableA> cq = cb.createQuery(TableA.class);
Root<TableA> ta = c.from(TableA.class);
Join<TableA, TableB> tb = ta.join("b");
Join<TableB, TableC> tc = tb.join("c");
cq.where(cb.and(
                cb.equal(ta.get("id"), tb.get("fid")), 
                cb.equal(tb.get("id"), tc.get("fid"))
               )
        );
cq.groupBy(ta.get("a"), tb.get("b"), tc.get("c"));
cb.select(cb.construct(com.dreamer.jpa.VABC.class, 
                        ta.get("id"), 
                        cb.diff(cb.sum(ta.get("a"), tb.get("b")), tc.get("c")),
                        ta.get("a"), 
                        tb.get("b"), 
                        tc.get("c")
                      )
          );
```

The result type of these queries is the `com.dreamer.jpa.VABC` class, that may be defined as follows:

```
package com.dreamer.jpa; //must conform the fully qualified name in the queries

public class VABC {
    private int id;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private BigDecimal a;
    private BigDecimal b;
    private BigDecimal c;

    public VABC(int id,BigDecimal total,BigDecimal a,BigDecimal b,BigDecimal c) {
        this.id = id;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, while executing query the persistence provider (query processor) iterates over the results of the query and for each table row being returned, a new instance of `com.dreamer.jpa.VABC` class is instantiated using the constructor that matches the expression types listed in the query.

This approach facilitates the process of constructing coarse-grained DTOs / VOs for use in other application tiers. Instead of manually constructing such objects from the result list a single query can be used to retrieve a complete list of objects i.e. already prepared for pushing into presentation layer.

---

Another option is to create an entity that directly maps into the existing database view. Thus you can make selections straight from the mapped view:

JPQL

```
SELECT v FROM VABC v
```

Criteria API

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<VABC> cq = cb.createQuery(VABC.class);
Root<VABC> ta = cq.from(VABC.class);
```

The entity class that refers to the database view may be defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "V_ABC")
public class VABC {
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal total;
    private BigDecimal a;
    private BigDecimal b;
    private BigDecimal c;

    public VABC(int id,BigDecimal total,BigDecimal a,BigDecimal b,BigDecimal c) {
        this.id = id;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Mapping the database view directly into an entity produces more concise code in comparison to *constructor expression* approach. In this case JPQL / Criteria based query produce a simple `SELECT id, total, a, b, c FROM V_ABC` while querying the database.

This approach also facilitates the process of constructing coarse-grained DTOs / VOs for use in other application tiers. A single query returns a complete list of VABC entity instances that represent V_ABC view rows.

Comment: Thanks! So can I say in this case then basically there is no need to create the view in the database? I thought for performance concern it is always better to leave the workload to Oracle instead of JPA(As JPA must add additional layer of process to translate JPQL/Criteria Query to SQL, and also I feel not all implementation of JPA doing very good job to convert JPQL to efficient SQL when there is a lot of joins)

Comment: I wouldn't say that. You may need to create the view for various purposes. Like usual - it's just a matter of choice between performance, portability, convenience, etc. I guess you are focused on performance therefore I would rather try to map the view into an entity and then use a native SQL query for data retrieval. I have updated my answer a little to make it more complete.